# How to identify multiple points with multiple buffers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have 40,000 house points that is mapped in GIS and another layer with all the amenities around the area. I am trying to find the number points of interests (POI) within a buffer of 500m from each house point.

How do I do that analysis it in ArcGIS so that it is exported into a table format - showing each house ID and the number of POI from a 500m buffer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What ArcGIS License do you have?  Have you looked into the [Near](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) tool (requires an Advanced license)?

Answer (score 5):

1. Buffer points - dissolve = none:
   [image]
2. Spatial Join
   [image]
3. Notice that ArcGIS has added the first field in the list 'Join_Count'.  This will record how many POIs intersect the Buffers.  The attribute table of the spatial join output will have all your attributes from the points, as well as the join count.
4. Export the spatial join result to excel and clean up the table.

Here is the table from my final spatial join output with the Join_Count field populated:

[image]

Comment: @bernie The best way to say "Thank You" here is to Upvote and Accept the answer!  Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)